# Nexus 7 2012 Not waking from sleep

Tags: nexus-7, sleep

Often, when I try to wake my nexus, the screen stays completely blank and the tablet refuses to do anything. To get my device working again I have to hold the power button for about 10 seconds, which hard resets the device. I unlocked my bootloader and installed cyanogenmod to see if that helped, but it didn't. This is extremely annoying as well as time wasting, driving me to the point where I just don't use my tablet anymore.

I have tried:

- Factory resetting the device
- Installing a new rom (A bunch of different cyanogenmod nightlies and snapshots)
- Waiting for the device to become responsive again

A quick Google search shows I'm definitely not the only person with this issue. I'll be happy to provide more information if need be.

Comment: So you're saying that the problem persist with ***stock kernel*** as well?

Comment: Yes. The reason I moved to cyanogenmod was because stock was acting up.

Comment: For the purpose of troubleshooting, can you backup your current ROM (optional) then flash stock ROM and see if the issue persist? I want to make sure that the kernel is not the problem here.

Comment: If possible, I would prefer to not flash any more ROMs unless absolutely necessary. I know for a fact this happens on stock because as I said in the post, I only switched to unofficial firmware because I was having the issue.

Comment: I'm in the process of trying to reproduce the problem and do a logcat. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: OK, so I've reproduced the problem and the nexus isn't wake-able. I've plugged the device into my PC to do a logcat, but doesn't show up in the terminal when I type `adb devices` like it would when wake-able.